# Symfony Many to Many relationship Persistent collection

Tags: symfony

Many to Many relationship:

I have two tables Joined with Many to Many relationship.

Account Group Entity:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Account", inversedBy="accountGroups", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn()},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")})
 **/
protected $accounts;
```

Account Entity:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AccountGroup", mappedBy="accounts", cascade={"persist"})
 * 
 */
protected $accountGroups;
```

I tried with Many to Many relationship for the accountgroup entity by using find() and findAll(). I am not getting any data related with the accounts even though it has. 
    I am getting persistent class collection with default dump.
    Whether it might be the relationship problem ?

Code used to Fetch :

$entityManager->getRepository('AccountGroup')->find(1);

Comment: Check your database and verify that your join table has the expected values.

Comment: Also, check if you are updating both sides of the relationship since they are bidirectional. [Docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Cerad and @Stiven Llupa Comments.
    I am getting relationship data. Iteration has to be done to get Individual Data.

```
$accountEntity = $entityManager->getRepository('Account')->find(1);
foreach($accountEntity->getAccountGroups() as $accountGroups) {
{
    echo $accountGroups->getId();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using wrong code. With

```
$entityManager->getRepository('AccountGroup')->find(1);
```

you'll find the row in the database that has an ID of 1. You need to do this:

```
$entityManager->getRepository('AccountGroup')->findBy(['group' => $group]);
```

with the `$group` variable containing the desired group.

Comment: Now that is just plain silly.  The problem is not finding the AccountGroup.  The problem is that the account group entity has no related accounts.  Probably because he did not cross reference his entities when creating them.

Comment: Yeah, that is not automatic. Maybe a simple `$em->refresh($accountGroup)` will get all the relations?

Comment: Nope.  Don't take this the wrong way but maybe you should go back and read the question more carefully before answering.

Comment: I've re-read it now and I'm not understanding it completly. Let's try this: if you do `$entityManager->getRepository('AccountGroup')->find(1)` what do you expect? What (instead) do you get? Also, why did you map ManyToMany? Shouldn't you use Many (account) to One (group)?